# Find all Combinations of 1 and 2 which sums up to k.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, algorithms, integer-partitions

I have two numbers $1$ and $2$. I have to print all ordered combinations which sums up to $k$.

For example:

$k=1$  Its only $1$.

$k=2$  It's ${1,1},{2}$.

$k=3$  Its ${1,1,1},{1,2},{2,1}$

What could be the algorithm to print these combinations ?

I could easily find the number of ways using Dynamic Programming like $f[n]=f[n-1]+f[n-2];$ where $f[0]=0,f[1]=1$ and $f[2]=2$.

Hence $f[3]=f[2]+f[1]=2+1=3$.
But my concern is to print these combinations.

Answer (score 1):

I am posting a recursive algorithm to print all such combinations. Hope this will be helpful.

`//prints all ordered combination of 1 and 2 which sum up to n 
 function printAll(n){
  //[] is empty list
   print(n,[])
 }
 function print(n,list){
  //base case 
  if(n==0){
    output all the elements in list
  }else{
    //passing a new list by appending "1" to "list"
    print(n-1,newlist(list,1))
    if(n>=2){
     //passing a new list by appending "2" to "list"
     print(n-2,newlist(list,2))
    }
  }
 }`

you will get output in this order for (n=4)

1 1 1 1

1 1 2

1 2 1

2 1 1

2 2